# Can I stay in Europe if I'm waiting for work visa for Germany after a work visa for sweden, but the swedish work visa expires

Tags: schengen, europe

Pretty much everything is in the question.

My girlfriend is from the US and has been working in Sweden for a couple of years now. She has applied for a work visa for Germany as she got a job there. However, the application is taking a long time and the Swedish visa will expire while she waits.

She will have to pick up her visa in Stockholm but she has a flat in Germany only at that point.

Can she stay in the EU while waiting for her application to be processed ?
Can she move between Sweden and Germany?

Answer (score 1):

As US citizen are allowed to travel without any VISA in the Schengen-Area for up to 90 days, is it possible to stay in EU meanwhile the German applciation is proceeded.

Answer (score 1):

Until the Swedish permit expires, she can stay in Sweden based on that. After that the 90/180 period will start for Sweden.

While the Swedish permit is valid, travel to **other** Schengen countries, the 90/180 rule applies for the **days outside** of Sweden making travel to Germany possible.

These rules apply independent of citizenship.

If she wants to leave Sweden now and move to her flat, she should ask the German Embassy person responsible for the processing of the work permit, if final issuing can be completed there

- depending on the the situation, this may be possible but must be clarified beforehand